# Bootstrap - vertical alignment of columns does not work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-5

I'm in the process of learning bootstrap, and I seem to be stuck at one of the most basic things - vertical alignment of columns. I am trying to get content to be anything but aligned at the top, but failing miserably.

I rewrote my code multiple times, but got no result. I started a new html document with just the code from bootstrap's documentation, but everything is still aligned at the top of the document. What am I missing here?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container text-center">
    <div class="row align-items-end">
      <div class="col">
        should be bottom - One of three columns
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        One of three columns
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        One of three columns
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you miss a height on the container. The default behavior is to `fit-content` and as such the elements height is only as height as the largest content. You have to define a height of the container higher than the default to allow a vertical centering.

Comment: @tacoshy, thank you for your kind reply. However, that didn't work. I set the height of the row to 300px, container to 600px, the body is 900px, and I still get top alignment using the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the `align-items-start` [class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#align-items) in Bootstrap.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container text-center vh-100">
    <div class="row align-items-center h-100">
      <div class="col">
        should be bottom - One of three columns
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        One of three columns
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        One of three columns
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. However, I am not looking for align-items-start. I am looking for either align-items-center or align-items-end, but I am getting only top aligned items.

Comment: The title in your question and what you explain in your question about what you want are a bit contradicting to this.

Comment: @aHamsterThatCodes Are you talking about like this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mc6te.png

Comment: @aHamsterThatCodes `align-items` works on a vertical axis that is determined by the `height` of the parenting container.

Comment: apologies for the confusion. The image you posted shows exactly what I want as the result. I did alter the height of the parent (the rows now have ample space to align), but did not get bottom/center alignment, only top

Comment: @aHamsterThatCodes See edits! You have to declare `heights` on your elements then. The easy way would be to use a viewport height `vh-100` on the `.container` div. Then you have to also set `h-100` on the row because you want that to fill the available `100vh`. Then, once you specify `align-items` it will be aligning them across the entire viewport, and not just the space they reserve initially.

Comment: setting heights on the container/row was the solution. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

To align all the items inside a grid we have multiple classes.

**1. All the item's text starts from the start with `align-items-start`**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container text-center">
    <div class="row align-items-start">
      <div class="col">
        should be bottom - One of three columns
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        One of three columns
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        One of three columns
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**All the items aligned vertically at the center with the `align-items-center` class**

````html
```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container text-center">
    <div class="row align-items-center">
      <div class="col">
        should be bottom - One of three columns
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        One of three columns
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        One of three columns
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```
````

**All text elements will be aligned at the end of the grid with `align-items-end` class **

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container text-center">
    <div class="row align-items-end">
      <div class="col">
        should be bottom - One of three columns
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        One of three columns
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        One of three columns
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

you can see all the alignments classes here

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/#align-items

Comment: thank you for taking the time to post the code above. However, the code I posted in my question came from the bootstrap page, and that is the one that does not deliver the results.